# Transfer URL Parameter into the facebook page

Tags: url, parameters, facebook-page

Is it possible to transfer URL parameter into the my Facebook page (app)?

It should look like this

https://www.facebook.com/mypage/app_777777777?mySID

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that for canvas/page tab apps, is the `app_data` parameter, whose content will be passed to your app on initial load as part of the `signed_request`.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Is there maybe one live downloadable example of this code usage? I need it for one simple things, I don't want to read and learn a lot of facebook api just for one little thing, that tells from what partner I am getting visitors.

Comment: Developing apps requires reading docs. If you’re not willing to do that, then I’d suggest you go for paid support.

Comment: I have consulted with programmer and he consumed, that this solution is not suitable for my case :( We need to transfer parameters only via URL. Otherwise we have to duplicate facebook pages a lot of times for each of our partners just to assign different SID for each page.

Comment: First of all, if you have a “programmer” working on this, why isn’t _he_ reading the docs (and asking questions here himself, if he has problems with it)? Second of all, using the `app_data` parameter __is__ a way of “transferring parameters via URL” (and it’s the _only_ way as well).